# Spinner selected item not showing when clicked

Tags: java, android, mvvm, spinner, android-room

I added a spinner that retrieves data from a room database
,when i click on the spinner it shows the available items correctly , but when i select one it doesn't appear in the spinner as selected and shows nothing

I found out that collegeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener 
isn't triggered even when i select something

```java
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    CollegeViewModel collegeViewModel;
    Spinner collegeSpinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);

        collegeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_college);
        final ArrayList<String> collegesList = new ArrayList<>();
        final CollegeAdapter collegeAdapter = new CollegeAdapter();
        collegeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CollegeViewModel.class);
        collegeViewModel.getAllColleges().observe(this, new Observer<List<College>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<College> colleges) {
                //this is what happens when when data changes // the code bellow should be related to changing the view
                collegeAdapter.setColleges(colleges);  // getting colleges from database and assigning it to collegeadapter
                for (int i = 0; i < collegeAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) { // accessing the adapter to add it's elements to collegeList
                    collegesList.add(collegeAdapter.getCollegeAt(i).getCollegeName());
                }
            }
        });
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.small_view, collegesList);
        collegeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        collegeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // this function doesn't work even when i select something
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // also doesn't work
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: It must work ... what is inside of you small_view layout?

Comment: Just a textview, Nothing is wrong with it, I found a solution, check it

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found a solution and i don't get exactly why it works 
but it's related to the fact that collegeAdapter is declared final but i have to declare it final otherwise i get an error in onChanged()

i made a function that adds elements from the collegeAdapter to collegeList 
so the function assigns the value of collegeAdapter to a new collegeAdapter in the parameter which isn't final and it worked like that

here how i implemented it

```java
collegeViewModel.getAllColleges().observe(this, new Observer<List<College>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<College> colleges) {
                //this is what happens when when data changes // the code bellow should be related to changing the view 
                collegeAdapter.setColleges(colleges);  // getting colleges from database and assigning it to collegeadapter
                addElements(collegeAdapter, collegesList); 
            }
        });
```

and here's the function

```java
public void addElements(CollegeAdapter collegeAdapter, ArrayList<String> collegesList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < collegeAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
            collegesList.add(collegeAdapter.getCollegeAt(i).getCollegeName());
        }
        collegeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
collegeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String str = collegeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                String str = llist.get(0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: those overridden functions aren't even triggered
i found another solution

Answer (score 0):

go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and then change source type to json and Annotation style to Gson copy your whole json in there and It make your whole json model in java class